# Is cardano native token ADA is same as the ADA balance I have in the wallet?

Tags: ada

Is the number of cardano native tokens ADA is same as the ADA balance I have in the wallet?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: if i have one ADA token then does it represent that i have 1 ADA as usable money in the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In the image below there is 243 ADA in that account, and 243 ADA is available. There are ways to lock up your ADA, like liquidity pools, abnormal staking, UTXO (wallets usually have more than one, and NFT's have to have a certain amount associated with them), spending passwords, etc. However generally speaking, if your wallet says you have it, you can spend it.

[image]